# Attribute 'explicit_arity' was not used

Tags: compiler-errors, ocamlbuild, reason

I'm trying to program using Jane Street's Core standard library and the Reason language frontend.

So I took the `corebuild` script and saved a copy as `recorebuild` by replacing `ocamlbuild` with `rebuild`. But I'm having trouble with some simple code.

This is the minimal example that fails:

```
type t = Foo int | Bar;

let foobar f => switch f {
| Foo x => x
| Bar => 0
};
```

If you try to compile it with the following option, one of the many added by `corebuild`:

```
rebuild -tag "ppx(ppx-jane -as-ppx)" test.byte
```

then you get this error:

```
File "", line 0:
Attribute `explicit_arity' was not used
Command exited with code 2.
```

What does it mean?

Comment: I'm interested in using Jane Street's Core in Reason too. Do you know of a doc/tutorial/blog explaining how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`explicit_arity` is an attribute emitted by `refmt` to resolve an ambiguity in the OCaml syntax regarding variants. Unfortunately it conflicts with a Jane St ppx, but it should work if you remove `-tag "ppx(ppx-jane -as-ppx)"` from the `corebuild` script.

(Note: This information is taken from the Reason Discord, I don't personally have any experience with this)

Comment: Can you link to the place that mentions it? Google didn't turn out much at all.

Comment: I don't have any links I'm afraid. But if you hop on the Reason Discord, https://discord.gg/reasonml (no registration required), you can search for it.

Comment: Actually, I think this is the issue that introduced it. Has a lot of discussion though: https://github.com/facebook/reason/issues/63